# Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)? rhierbaps

Tags: r

I am trying to run rhierbaps in R in a set of 729 strains, here is the code that I am using (exactly the same as that in the example used for the program):

```
#load data
fasta.rhierBAPS_Ef <- system.file("extdata", "Concatenated.fas", package = "rhierbaps")

#SNP Matrix
snp.matrix <- load_fasta(fasta.rhierBAPS_Ef)

#rhierBAPS
hb.results <- hierBAPS(snp.matrix, max.depth = 2, n.pops = 10, n.extra.rounds = Inf, 
                       quiet = TRUE)
```

and when I do this a get the error:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup:
```

Then Rstudio Blocks and aborts...

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have erroneously specified: n.pops = 0
Use a positive integer as the upper bound and it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much Jukka. I also found that my computer actually lacks RAM to make these big analysis so I configured in the Command pront the --max.ppsize for 50000 and now I am able to run the script:  
hb.results <- hierBAPS(snp.matrix, max.depth = 2, n.pops = 20, quiet = TRUE) without any problems. Thank you very much for your help and suggestions